# How To Completely Rebuild A Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Not entirely sure what I am asking but I will attempt to try and explain what I want.

I have a `docker-compose` file. And from the command line I type in...

`docker-compose up`

The first time this ever happens it tells me it is `pulling` the docker image and then `downloading` it,  `building` it and `running` it.

Sometimes I need to change the docker-compose file and I would like to just re-do the entire process (as specified above).

But.... the only way I can see to do this is to go the the GUI of docker (on mac) and hit the `bomb` icon to factory reset the entire thing.

Of course this nukes my other docker images (which feels like a sledgehammer to crack a nut).

Can anybody furnish me with a command that will reset and force and entire fresh download of an image?

Comment: In my case `docker-compose build --no-cache` was the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So my understanding of what you're asking for is to be able to make the **very first run of a `docker compose up` operation repeatable**

So docker provides the following commands:

`docker images <image_name>`

This lists all the images for a given name. It works with wildcards too, so if all your images are prefixed then `docker images my_app*` works

To get just the image ids, you use `docker images <image_name> -q` ... this gives just the image id ... you can go `docker images <image_name> golang -q && docker images postgres` as an example to list your image ids

Now you take those ids and use `docker rmi <image_id>` which will delete the image.

**TL;DR;**

So putting it all together you go:

`` docker rmi `docker images <image_name> -q && docker images <image_name> -q` ``

I think the backtick technique will work in OSX (under bash), but if it doesn't you just want to evaluate the image ids first before `docker rmi` is called. Let me know and I'll remove this paragraph.

Note that this will only remove your images, if you have volumes attached you may need to remove those as well. I think `docker-compose down -v` does this for you, but I need to confirm a bit later when I tidy the answer up.

Answer (score 2):

```
docker build -t ignitus-rest:latest .
```

will do the job :)

Answer (score -2):

If your problem is caching you can use the something along the lines of --no-cache (check the docker docs) to force a rebuild of all the steps from the start.

if you would like to remove the image this command should help

`docker ps -a` , to get all the images, choose the correct id

`docker rmi $id` , should do the trick